# Anchor links don't work in gatsby project

Tags: gatsby

I use `gatsby-transformer-remark` to parse markdown files and [get table of contents](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/#getting-table-of-contents). If I hit an item in table of contents (anchor link), the browser doesn't scroll to the section.

I created a basic demo project [here](https://github.com/AndrejGajdos/gatsby-anchor-test). If you open for example `http://localhost:8000/docs/tauchain-agoras-faqs` and scroll to the bottom, you can see table of content there.

I created a [recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MMAVbxMY3bWFlqRmg-d0GjopaX2h0tY3/view?usp=sharing), where I click on items in table of contents and nothing happens but browser should scroll to clicked section.

Comment: This is probably the same issue: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is suggested in https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25554 it's an issue related to `gatsby-react-router-scroll` dependency last pull request.

Your [`yarn.lock`](https://github.com/AndrejGajdos/gatsby-anchor-test/blob/master/gatsby-anchor-test/yarn.lock#L5958) shows a `3.0.7` version. Try to downgrade it to `3.0.3` and should do the trick.